# Creating model relationships/Nested resourses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

Hi I am trying to create a relationship between two models Establishments and OpenClosed I have added

```
class Establishment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :open_closed
end

class OpenClosed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :establishment
end
```

I have added establishment_id field to open_closed table and then ran rails db:migrate.Next I've nested the resources

```
resources :establishments do
  resources :open_closeds
end
```

Then I modified the OpenClosed controller #new line comment where I've added new code

```
def new
 @establishment = Establishment.find(params[:establishment_id]) #new line added
 @open_closed = OpenClosed.new
end

 # GET /open_closeds/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /open_closeds
# POST /open_closeds.json
def create
 @establishment = Establishment.find(params[:establishment_id]) #new line added
 @open_closed = OpenClosed.new(open_closed_params)
 @open_closed.Establishment = @establishments #new line added

respond_to do |format|
  if @open_closed.save
    format.html { redirect_to @open_closed, notice: 'Open closed was       successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @open_closed }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @open_closed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

This is the error I'm getting when I submit form in open_closed view:

undefined method `Establishment=' for # Did you mean? establishment= establishment establishment_id= establishment_id establishment_id?

Can not for the life of me work out where I'm going wrong here could someone please point me in the right direction with this one many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a OpenClosed? Do you mean something like [business hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_hours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite the `OpenClosed#new` action to look like this:

```
<h1>New Open Closed</h1>

<%= render 'form', establishment: @establishment, open_closed: @open_closed %>
<%= link_to 'Back', establishment_open_closeds_path %>
```

This means we are now passing in an `Establishment` object and a `OpenClosed` object to the form partial.

Next, change the `<%= form_for ... %>` declaration at

```
`app/views/open_closeds/_form.html.erb`
```

to look like this:

```
<%= form_for [establishment, open_closed] do |f| %>
```

We've just told our form to use both the `Establishment` and `OpenClosed` object.

Next, rewrite the open_closed controller to look like this:

```
def create
  @establishment = Establishment.find(params[:establishment_id])
  @open_closed = OpenClosed.new(open_closed_params)
  @open_closed.Establishment = @establishment #new line added

  respond_to do |format|
    if @open_closed.save
      format.html { redirect_to [@establishment, @open_closed], notice: 'Open closed was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @open_closed }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @open_closed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The two modifications I made were:

changing the line

```
@open_closed.Establishment = @establishments
```

to

```
@open_closed.establishment = @establishment
```

Note that the 'e' in establishment is now lowercase and I removed the 's' at the end of the line (that was probably just a typo). If you look at your `db/schema.rb` file, you should see

```
t.integer  "establishment_id"
```

under the `open_closeds` table. In ActiveRecord, you access the methods of your class using the same name as the row in your database table. However, for foreign keys like `establishment_id`, rails is smart enough to know that when you say `@open_closed.establishment`, you really just want the `Establishment` that belongs to your `OpenClosed` object.

The second thing I changed in the above code is this line:

```
redirect_to [@establishment, @open_closed] ...
```

You need to provide both the establishment and open_closed objects in order for the route to be valid. Since the redirect statement is sending you to the show method of the OpenClosed class, you can run rake routes to see what the route for `OpenClosed#show` looks like. I ran `rake routes` on your route file and got this for the show method of OpenClosed

```
establishment_open_closed GET    /establishments/:establishment_id/open_closeds/:id(.:format)      open_closeds#show
```

So you can see that `OpenClosed#show` is expecting both an Establishment object and an OpenClosed object. You simply need to provide both objects in an array as the first parameter to `redirect_to`

## NOTE:

You will likely still get an error when you try this because many of the routes in the application are incorrect and need to changed. For example, to actually render the `OpenClosed#show` view (which is where you're redirected after a successful call to `OpenClosed#create`), you will need to make the following modifications to the show template of the OpenClosed controller:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_establishment_open_closed_path(@open_closed) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', establishment_open_closeds_path %>
```

As a tip for the future, you can add

`<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>` in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file directly after the yield. This will print out server response information which can useful when debugging.

Lastly, there are going to be other parts of you application that won't work until you fix the routes, but hopefully you have enough info to do that now.

For more information on nested routes, check out the [official rails guids](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Happing coding!

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer it really made me understand it so much more, after spending a couple of hours sorting out my routes I have it working thanks to your advice. Nice little learning curve Cheers.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like that:

```
@open_closed = @establishment.open_closeds.new(open_closed_params)
```

so it'll assign @open_closed.establishment_id for you.

Also seems like you need to change `has_many :open_closed` to `has_many :open_closeds`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@open_closed.Establishment = @establishments #new line added
```

This is the line that's failing.
That should be:

```
@open_closed.establishment = @establishment #new line added
```

Note that capitalisation really matters. Your associated object is never going to start with a capital letter - capital letters are for class names (eg when you are defining the Establishment model) or constants (which you are't using here).

Also note you have a typo -> `@establishment` is not plural (there's only one) :)

Comment: Class names are constants

Comment: but different to ALL_SHOUTY_CONSTANTS :) they're in a class of their own (hehe)

Comment: Ruby does not differentiate between ALLCAPS and CamelCase - as long as it starts with a uppercase letter its a constant. `class Foo; end` is actually just syntactic sugar for `Foo = Class.new `. You could declare your classes `LIKE_BACK_WHEN_FORTRAN_WAS_THE_BEES_KNEES = Class.new` but it might lead to tarring and feathering and a soap beatdown behind the water cooler.

Comment: Yes, Ruby does work that way, but for a beginner rails developer - the distinction really isn't important, and it's better for them to learn that Classes start with a single capital, and they are not quite the same thing as an ALLCAPS constant... this is better for memorising standard Rails practices. The detail that they could plausibly be treated the same way as each other if you really wanted to break with standard rails naming/capitalisation practices really isn't important to know.